# multiple trendlines being plotted R, only want the best fit model

Tags: r, plot, non-linear-regression, trendline

I am trying to plot some trendlines for a non linear fit in R using the follwing code:

```
plot(X53.023_9.198~IDV,data=cor_data)

eq_power<- function(a,b){a*IDV^b} 

fit<-nlsLM(X53.023_9.198~eq_power(a,b),
        start = list(a = 1, b = 1),
        control = list(minFactor=0, maxiter=nls_iterations),
        data=cor_data)

lines(IDV, predict(fit), col = "red",lty=2,lwd=3)
```

However, I am getting multiple trendlines showing up in the graph (see below), what am I doing wrong?

[image: obtained plot]

the data is as follows:

| IDV | X53.023_9.198 |
| --- | --- |
| 2.017965 | 0.946996284 |
| 2.387598 | 1.458080549 |
| 1.183276 | 1.526326488 |
| 0.33767 | 1.137685393 |
| 1.010474 | 0.819575382 |
| 1.536974 | 0.995749356 |
| 0.33767 | 0.209826676 |
| 2.387598 | 1.107859879 |
| 2.017965 | 1.210650039 |
| 2.3436 | 0.821578704 |
| 1.536974 | 0.932842489 |
| 2.3436 | 1.247124105 |
| 1.010474 | 0.585704654 |

Comment: The data must be sorted first.

Comment: Sorry, I am still pretty much a beginner in R, how do I sort it?

Comment: `cor_data <- cor_data[order(cor_data$IDV), ]`

Comment: your code did not work for me (argument 1 is not a vector) but just sorted it by hand and it works now. thanks!